# Avconv ac3 to aac or mp3 is not synced with video

Tags: avconv

I'm trying to convert a MPEG2 file to H264/AAC.

No problem about video, but when I convert *Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 255 kb/s* to MP3 or AAC, with any bitrate, the sound is not synced with the video. The sound is in advanced to video when I play it.
How to fix it please ?

More information : the source video is 1h30 long and 3,4 Gio.

Answer (score 3):

To sync the audio stream with video time stamps we may use the `-async` option:

> ***`-async samples_per_second`***
>   Audio sync method. "Stretches/squeezes" the audio stream to match the timestamps, the parameter is the maximum samples per second by which the audio is changed. -async 1 is a special case where only the start of the audio stream is corrected without any later correction. This option has been deprecated. Use the asyncts audio filter instead.
>   <sup>[Libav documentation](http://libav.org/avconv.html#toc-Advanced-options)</sup>

Begin to try with samples per second matching your framerate and decrease until your audio is in sync:

```
avconv -async 30 -i <infile> <encoding options> -r 30 <outfile>
```