# Audio and video auto of sync when streaming

Tags: sound, video, sync, streaming

When streaming my desktop to twitch.tv using `avconv` audio and video are out of sync. Sometimes it is already out of sync when starting the stream and sometimes they just drift apart after a while.
This is the script I use for streaming:

```
#!/bin/bash
INRES="1920x1080" # input resolution
OUTRES="1280x720"
OFFSET="0,0"
FPS="30" # target FPS
MAXRATE="3000k"
BUFSIZE="3000k"
AUDIOBITRATE="192k"
QUAL="medium" # one of the many FFMPEG preset
STREAM_KEY=$(cat ~/.twitch_key)
URL="rtmp://live.twitch.tv/app/$STREAM_KEY"
SHOW_REGION="0"

avconv -v quiet -f x11grab -show_region $SHOW_REGION -s "$INRES" -r "$FPS" -i :0.0+$OFFSET \
-f alsa -ac 2 -b:a "$AUDIOBITRATE" -i pulse -c:v libx264 -crf 30 -preset "$QUAL" \
-s "$OUTRES" -vol 11200 -c:a libmp3lame -ar 44100 -pix_fmt yuv420p -maxrate "$MAXRATE" -bufsize "$BUFSIZE" \
-f flv "$URL"

exit $?
```

Comment: Try with the `-async` option: http://askubuntu.com/questions/227497/avconv-ac3-to-aac-or-mp3-is-not-synced-with-video

Comment: @Takkat This option makes the sound stutter completely.

Comment: This piece of software looks fine: http://www.maartenbaert.be/simplescreenrecorder/  This commit also seems to address the issue I described here: https://github.com/MaartenBaert/ssr/commit/a79107189fc4bc3a7b39104c340836310770a599

Answer (score 3):

When ssr outputs:

```
Warning: Audio input is more than 5% too fast, video and audio will be out of sync.
```

or

```
Warning: Audio input is more than 5% too slow, video and audio will be out of sync.
```

Do this:

> Edit `/etc/pulse/daemon.conf`, make sure it contains these lines (adding or uncommenting):
>
> ```
> default-sample-rate = 44100
> alternate-sample-rate = 44100
> ```

There is an [upstream bug](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=66424) which is marked as fixed but the patch is not in the repository of Ubuntu.
The [simplescreenrecorder bug](https://github.com/MaartenBaert/ssr/issues/16) which contains this workaround.