# audio track framerate 25(PAL)-->23,976(NTSC)

Tags: command-line, sound, ffmpeg, multimedia

here's my problem: I need to change the framerate of the audio track of one of my films from 25 to 23,976 fps (to mux it with a full hd version); I used to make use of handbrake, re-encoding the film at highspeed and changing the framerate, setting the audio at high quality
This time, I'd like to change the framerate WITHOUT affecting the audio quality nor re-encoding with a different format.

Is there a way? (maybe ffmpeg?-->if so, please post the commands)

Please someone help me

Comment: Take a look at [Avidemux](http://fixounet.free.fr/avidemux/)

Comment: You may try to sync audio to the output file (see http://askubuntu.com/questions/227497/avconv-ac3-to-aac-or-mp3-is-not-synced-with-video), or `asyncts` in newer versions. This may however also re-encode audio (no sure about that).

Comment: That's right, Avidemux looks (and works) nice, but it won't sync the audio :(

Comment: Takkat, I'll try that too