# avconv/ffmpeg - audio slowly drifts out of sync, original is in sync

Tags: sound, video, ffmpeg, avconv, convert

Almost all of the instructions I've read about drifting audio sync is regarding live screen recording. **I'm simply trying to truncate useless video from the end of a raw DV file in an effort to prepare it to be burned to DVD, whether that involves actual truncation or converting it to a different format, I do not care**

So I've got tons of VHS home videos that I'm trying to convert, here's the process:

Using Kino, record VHS into Raw DV format. Since it can take a couple hours to record a VHS, I usually walk away. When I return, the VHS is finished playing but Kino is still recording, leaving a lot of blank space at the end of the DV file being recorded.

At this point, the Raw DV file is perfectly in sync and great quality, but I'm trying to remove the blank space at the end so I can burn it to DVD. After removal, the finshed file has synced audio at the start, but by the end (an hour or two later), it can be as much as 3 to 5 seconds off, it's a gradual drift. Here's some of the options I've tried:

```
avconv -i inputvideo.dv -codec copy -ss 00:00:00 -t 1:37:35 output.dv
```

(gives an error "Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters?)" but I've read a bunch of documentation, I can't figure out what parameters I'm missing)

```
avconv -i inputvideo.dv -target ntsc-dvd -ss 00:00:00 -t 1:37:35 output.mpg
```

(awful quality, still drifts out of sync)

```
sudo /usr/bin/avconv -y -i \
"/media/techmachine/Backup/inputvideo.dv" \
-f dvd \
-target ntsc-dvd \
-r 30000/1001 \
-filter:v scale=720:480 \
-aspect 4:3 \
-vb 8000k \
-mbd rd \
-trellis 1 \
-flags +mv0 \
-cmp 0 \
-subcmp 2 \
-ss 00:00:00 \
-t 1:37:35 \
"/media/techmachine/Backup/Finished/output.mpg"
```

(This is a line I got from WinFF, specifically the "DVD HQ" option. Good Quality, still drifts out of sync)

Comment: To stop you from murdering somebody: there is an option `-async`. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/227497/avconv-ac3-to-aac-or-mp3-is-not-synced-with-video

Comment: @Takkat I was under the impression that the source video file needed "timestamps" in order to use that correctly. Documentation says async is deprecated for asyncts which requires timestamps.

Comment: Did you try it? My version here obviously is compiled without `asyncts`support (it spits out `Unrecognized option asyncts`).

Comment: @Takkat I'm trying it now, takes a while, will give you credit if it works

Comment: Try a recent [static build of `ffmpeg`](http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/). It often works where `avconv` and/or the counterfeit "`ffmpeg`" in the repo fails.

Comment: @Takkat unfortunately, it was still out of sync. This is what I used: avconv -async 30 -i inputvideo.dv -target dv -ss 00:00:00 -t 1:37:35 -r 30 ./Finished/test.dv

Comment: @LordNeckbeard Any recommendations on parameters? I'm going to use ffmpeg -i inputvideo.dv -target dv -ss 00:00:00 -t 1:37:35 ./Finished/test.dv unless you have other suggestions.

Comment: @MALON `-target dv` should be `-target ntsc-dv` or `-target pal-dv`.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard I let the -target dv finish, still unsynced by end of video. Will try again with -target ntsc-dv

Comment: @LordNeckbeard Still no good. This was the command I used: sudo /home/techmachine/Desktop/ffmpeg-2.4.2-32bit-static/ffmpeg -i /media/techmachine/Backup/inputvideo.dv -target ntsc-dv -ss 00:00:00 -t 1:37:35 /media/techmachine/Backup/Finished/test/outputvideo.dv

Comment: Have you tried extracting the audio and video from the original files and playing them separately and seeing whether they have the same length?  If not: resample the audio to have the same length as the video and then recombine...